Python Certificate error during TLS handshake to gmail SMTP server
I write a client program which tries to send mail to Gmail SMTP server by smtplib and ssl.SSLContext objects,  but get an error when loading a cert PEM file during TLS handshake :
import ssl, smtplib, email

def send_email(subject, body, sender, recipients, password):
    mml = email.message.EmailMessage()
    mml.set_content(body)
    mml['From'] = sender
    mml['To'] = ', '.join(recipients)
    mml['Subject'] = subject
    sslctx = ssl.SSLContext(protocol=ssl.PROTOCOL_TLS_CLIENT)
    sslctx.verify_mode = ssl.CERT_REQUIRED
    assert sslctx.verify_mode == ssl.CERT_REQUIRED
    sslctx.load_verify_locations(cafile='crt.pem', capath='.')
    hdlr = smtplib.SMTP(host='smtp.gmail.com', port=587) # do not use SMTP_SSL
    hdlr.starttls(context=sslctx)
    hdlr.login('my-account-xxx@gmail.com', password)
    hdlr.sendmail(sender, recipients, mml.as_string())
    print("[INFO] Message sent!")


> gmail_demo.send_email(subject='someone testing this site', body='there <b>you</b> go', sender='system@yourproject.io', recipients=['another-person@gmail.com'], password='abcdef123456')
>
> Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  ssl.SSLError: [SSL] PEM lib (_ssl.c:3917)

From that error message, I found it is reported by the C extension module in cpython , it seems that the method SSLContext.load_cert_chain() is implemented at here .
My questions :

Does SSLContext.load_cert_chain(...) require callers to provide valid keyfile argument ? In the doc the argument keyfile is optional, however in C implementation , this error is likely from the return value of SSL_CTX_use_PrivateKey_file(...) .
Is there anything incorrect in my cert file  crt.pem ?  The file contains a cert I downloaded from gmail SMTP server, by following the instructions in this google workplace admin help.

About the environment : CPython 3.12.0
Thanks

if your using google workspace why not just use a service account.  Why are you using login and password and why the smtp server?

I don't use google workspace , I simply come across the doc when looking for gmail SMTP setup , currently this is part of my side project so gmail smtp server should do things well  .

You shouldn't have to do any of that. No need for an SSLContext at all, and no need for any certificate loading, unless you are running a very outdated system or you want to implement certificate pinning.

Thanks for feedback James, and yes I was trying to implement certificate pinning .  I understand Python should search for the correct CA cert in default paths depending on users' operating system platform (e.g. /etc/ssl/certs in Linux), but there might be few cases users would prefer to specify path to the cert outside the default folders.

After carefully reading these documentations and this stackoverflow answer, I found the mistakes I made :

In ssl.SSLContext , the method load_cert_chain(...) is for server-side peer signing a  certificate with the CA, then sending the server certificate to client-side peer which will validate it , in such case the private key is required ; But in my case it is impossible to have private key of the gmail certificate, I should instead use another method load_verify_locations(...) which only loads certificate chain.
It is essential to prepare all the required certificates for the first time to connect to the gmail SMTP server in my development environment. In my case, issuers of the certificates are smtp.gmail.com, google trusted services 1c3 , and its CA google trusted services root R1 . As described in the python doc , the file PEM file should look like :

-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
... (cert for the gmail smtp server)...
-----END CERTIFICATE-----
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
... (cert for google trusted services 1c3, which signs the gmail server cert)...
-----END CERTIFICATE-----
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
... (cert for google trusted services root R1, which signs google trusted services 1c3 cert)...
-----END CERTIFICATE-----


As I noted in my comment above, none of these certificates are needed. But if you did need one it would only be the root certificate since the TLS server sends the other two.
